# How to force a newline

Tags: line-breaking

I want to have a new line after a bold written text.

Sadly the following LaTeX code does not work (this is my original section):

```
\section{Analyse des Firefox-Source-Code}
Der Source Code von Firefox wird analysiert mit dem Ziel herauszufinden wo und v.a. wie firefox nachträglich geladene Elemente verwaltet. Es ist nicht gelungen die erhofften Informationen zu entnehmen aber alle Erkenntnisse und Informationen welche für eine weiterführung des Projektes hilfreich sein können werden im folgenden aufgeführt.

\subsection{Die Methode HasHeaderValue}
Eine sehr interessante und häufig genutzte Methode ist die in der Datei \texttt{/netwerk/protocol/http/nsHttpResponseHead.h} definierte Methode \texttt{HasHeaderValue}. Diese Methode überprüft ob einer Eigenschaft, welche ein HTTP-Response enthalten kann, ein bestimmter Wert zugewiesen ist. Ein Beispiel hierfür wäre ob die Eigenschaft \texttt{"Cache-Control"} den Wert \texttt{"must-revalidate"} enthält. In diesem Beispiel würde bei jeder veränderung der Inhalte einer Webseite, diese komplett neu geladen werden müssen.

\begin{figure}[htbp]
    \centering
        \includegraphics{Ablaufdiagramm_HasHeaderValue.png}
    \caption{Aufrufdiagramm externer Methoden beginnend bei HasHeaderValue}
    \label{fig:Ablaufdiagramm_HasHeaderValue}
\end{figure}

\pagebreak
\textbf{Zu 5.)}

Das struct \texttt{entry} beinhaltet zwei Variablen genannt \texttt{header} und \texttt{value}. Die Methode \texttt{entry.get()} soll die Variable \texttt{value} zurückliefern. Also den Wert des headers, beispielsweise \texttt{must-revalidate} für \texttt{Cache-Control}.
\\
\textbf{Zu 4.)}

In der Methode \texttt{LookupEntry} sind nur zwei für uns wichtige Zeilen nämlich: 
\begin{verbatim}
 *entry = &mHeaders[index];
return entry ? entry->value.get() : nullptr;
\end{verbatim}
Da \texttt{LookupEntry} mithilfe der Adresse eines $($nsEntry$)$ Pointers\footnote{Deutsch: Zeiger. Werden verwendet um mit Adressen von Variablen zu arbeiten.} aufgerufen wird, erhält dieser Pointer die Adresse des Entry-Wertes welcher gesucht war.
In der zweiten Zeile wird geprüft ob \texttt{entry} ein \texttt{nullptr}, also ein leerer Pointer, ist. Wenn dies nicht der Fall ist wird durch \texttt{value.get}, wie oben beschrieben, der Wert des Headers als Pointer zurückgegeben. Sollte \texttt{entry} aber ein \texttt{nullptr} sein wird auch ein \texttt{nullptr} zurückgegeben.
Also ist der Rückgabewert der Methode \texttt{PeekHeader} entweder ein String welcher den Wert des Headers enthält oder ein leerer Pointer.
\\
\textbf{Zu 3.)}

\texttt{FindToken} liefert in drei Fällen einen \texttt{nullptr} zurück. Diese sind:
\begin{itemize}
    \item \texttt{input} ist leer $($Der erste Parameter der Methode$)$
    \item die Länge von \texttt{input} ist kleiner als die Länge des gesuchten Strings
    \item es wurde kein übereinstimmender String gefunden
\end{itemize}
Der Rückgabewert von \texttt{FindToken} ist ein char\footnote{kurz für Character. Zu Deutsch: Zeichen.} Pointer welcher, sollte kein \texttt{nullptr} zurückgegeben werden, auf das Vorkommen in dem gegebenen \texttt{input} zeigt, vor und hinter dem ein Seperator für HTTP gesetzt ist.
Ein Seperator für HTTP ist nach Firefox als einfaches Komma definiert.

\\
\textbf{Zu 2.)}

\texttt{FindHeaderValue} erhält nun den char Pointer und gibt diesen zurück.

\\
\textbf{Zu 1.)}

\texttt{HasHeaderValue} überprüft ob der von \texttt{FindHeaderValue} erhaltene Pointer ein \texttt{nullptr} ist und gibt dementsprechend einen Wahrheitswert zurück.
```

The referred picture in the beginning of the section:

[image]

Btw. the newlines I want to force have aesthetic reasons.

Is there a way to actually **force** a newline no matter what happens?

Comment: You would do well to read an introduction to LaTeX.  …no I'm serious, come back once you've read an introduction. This is *not* how it's meant to be used – it's a small wonder that you're having problems.

Comment: Sorry if I seemed a little mean up there :) but truly, your problem could be solved by simply using the `enumerate` environment (you can set the label styles easily with either the `enumerate` or `enumitem` packages). There is another way to do it, but it ignores the core problem in your document.

Comment: why are you using `$)$` ?  The only affect there is to protect the `)` from the surrounding `\textbf` so you get a non-bold `)`.  (But you should avoid having explicit font changes and manual numbering in LaTeX documents)

Comment: I did use `$)$` because without them the `)` would not have been displayed. I did not know that there is no need for that in `\textbf{}`. I fixed that. thx

And the manual numbering is referring to a graphic I have inserted in the document. Editing the post. giving you the picture

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can only add a newline after the end of a paragraph, not on "the middle of nothing". Since you didn't provide an [MWE](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/a/231/75142), I will only paste part of your text with a possible solution to the problem. As you said, you want a newline after the bold item, so you can add `\\` immediately after the command (as my code shows below). Pay attention to the `\\` with `[]` specifying the height of a new line. You can specify the desired value inside the brackets.

```
Der Rückgabewert von \texttt{FindToken} ist ein char
\footnote{kurz für Character. Zu Deutsch: Zeichen.}
Pointer welcher, sollte kein \texttt{nullptr} zurückgegeben werden, 
auf das Vorkommen in dem gegebenen \texttt{input} zeigt, vor und 
hinter dem ein Seperator für HTTP gesetzt ist. Ein Seperator für HTTP 
ist nach Firefox als einfaches Komma definiert.\\[1PC]

\textbf{Zu 2.)}\\[2PC]

\texttt{FindHeaderValue} erhält nun den char Pointer und 
gibt diesen zurück.
```

Answer (score 3):

Does this look good to you?

[image: output]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{enumitem}
\setlist[enumerate]{label=\textbf{\arabic*)}}

\usepackage{mwe}
\begin{document}
\lipsum[1]
\begin{enumerate}
\item \texttt{Some} text I have written.
\item \texttt{some} other text that I have written
\end{enumerate}
\lipsum[2]
\end{document}
```

Comment: I would like to accept this. The problem is that my items do not start with simple numbers only. 
It will look something like:
`\item [Zu 4.$)$] \lipsum[1]`

Meaning that I have a very long text in one item and that the left border would be crossed

Comment: Then can you give a real example that demonstrates the diversity of your use?

Answer (score 2):

I have "fixed" the problem using the  `\vspace{7}` command.
I will of course accept an Answer which has a better solution but for anyone with the same problem this is a temporary... let´s call it "fix".

Comment: http://www.thelazymathematician.com/2013/02/enumerate-using-enumitem.html if you don't want to read `enumitem` documentation. For reverse numbering use `etarenume` package. And don't mess with `\vspace`s, it is like riding a mountain bike without using gearshift at all.